# Using the DECODE Function

Tags: sql, oracle, decode

Could someone help me with the code below. I am trying the perform the task outlined below. Is it possible to decode using parameters?

DECODE (:START_DATE, NULL, a.issue_date >=(trunc(trunc(sysdate,'MONTH')-1,'MONTH')),a.issue_date >= :START_DATE)
DECODE (:END_DATE, NULL,  a.issue_date <= (trunc(sysdate,'MONTH')-1), a.issue_date <= :END_DATE)

The programming language I am using is SQL.

Comment: What, exactly, is "the task outlined below" trying to do?

Comment: I have two parameters called START_DATE and END_DATE. I would like persons to enter a start date and end date  so that date data is displayed between those two parameters entered.Also, when the parameters are left null, i would like the date information displayed to be  for the previous month (ie. the first and last day of the previous month)

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?  Hope this helps.

```
select *
from <table> a
where a.issue_date between DECODE (:START_DATE, NULL, (trunc(trunc(sysdate,'MONTH')-1,'MONTH')), :START_DATE) 
and DECODE (:END_DATE, NULL,  (trunc(sysdate,'MONTH')-1), :END_DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think DECODE is helping you here.  It works, but, in my opinion, it makes the code harder to read.  I think these are your two conditions.  (1) issue_date compared to the users input.  (2) if the users input values are both null, then compare with date values of the beginning and end of the previous month.  Also, using the DECODE may make it so that if there is an index on issue_date, it may not be able to use it.

```
select *
from   table a
where  (a.issue_date >= :START_DATE and a.issue_date <= :END_DATE)
   OR  (:START_DATE is null AND :END_DATE IS NULL 
        AND a.issue_date >= TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1),'MONTH') AND a.issue_date < TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MONTH')
```